# how to revert back the newline character when content is copied from browser

Tags: android, html, browser, copy, newline

I got to know that some older version of browser take new line character as single space.
Is there a method to revert back to that newline character when the content is copied?
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible when copying the rendered output; however if you can leverage the underlying markup you could obviously treat a newline as you desire before moving it to the clipboard.

You have to remember that the browser [treats line breaks as white space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.1) and thus [condenses the white space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space) as it renders the markup.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but i just wanted to know how can we get the underlying markup when we copy the content?

Comment: You would need to parse the HTML as noted [here](http://blog.andrewpearson.org/2010/07/android-html-parsing.html).