# How can I echo or print an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
  [data] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
        (
          [page_id] => 204725966262837
          [type] => WEBSITE
        )

      [1] => Array
        (
          [page_id] => 163703342377960
          [type] => COMMUNITY
        )
      )
)
```

How can I just echo the content without this structure?

I tried

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->type;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

This will do

```
foreach($results['data'] as $result) {
    echo $result['type'], '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you tell me how can I echo for example only the type of the Array [1] ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos `echo $results['data'][1]['type'];`

Comment: What if I dont have any key like `data`?

Comment: @PratikButani use var_dump($array) to get more information of the content of the array

Comment: how can I insert this information in a database? for example, if I have a table with a column named `type` and i want o insert [0]['type'] , [1]['type'] and so on?

Answer (score 605):

To see the contents of array you can use:

1. `print_r($array);` or if you want nicely formatted array then:

   ```
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
   ```
2. Use `var_dump($array)` to get more information of the content in the array like the datatype and length.
3. You can loop the array using php's `foreach();` and get the desired output. More info on *foreach* is in PHP's documentation website: *[foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)*

Comment: This answer does not address the mistake that OP did.

Comment: @Robin <pre> tag displays new lines and tabulation as it's outputed by print_r(); without <pre> you would see a messy unformatted bounds of data. To see it formatted you should then view the html page source.

Answer (score 142):

If you just want to know the content without a format (e.g., for debugging purposes) I use this:

```
echo json_encode($anArray);
```

This will show it as a JSON which is pretty human-readable.

Comment: I wanted to extract some data from a `html - php` document using Cordova `InAppBrowser` `executeScript` method, without `json_encode($array)` I could not achieve that! Thanks a lot @Mark E

Comment: echo json_encode($downloads, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); works even better

Answer (score 57):

There are multiple functions for printing array content that each has features.

### [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Prints human-readable information about a variable.

```php
$arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

```php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

```php
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

### [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Displays structured information about expressions that includes its type and value.

```php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

```php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

### [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Displays structured information about the given variable that returned representation is valid PHP code.

```php
echo "<pre>";
var_export($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

```php
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
)
```

Note that because the browser condenses multiple whitespace characters (including newlines) to a single space ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588362/5104748)), you need to wrap above functions in `<pre></pre>` to display result in thee correct format.

---

Also, there is another way to print array content with certain conditions.

### [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Output one or more strings. So if you want to print array content using `echo`, you need to loop through the array and in the loop use `echo` to print array items.

```php
foreach ($arr as $key=>$item){
    echo "$key => $item <br>";
}
```

```php
0 => a
1 => b
2 => c
```

Answer (score 35):

You can use [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [`var_export`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) functions of PHP:

`print_r`: Convert into human-readable form

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

`var_dump()`: will show you the type of the thing as well as what's in it.

```
var_dump($results);
```

`foreach loop`: using a *for each* loop, you can iterate each and every value of an array.

```
foreach($results['data'] as $result) {
    echo $result['type'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: how to insert the result in a database?

Comment: tell me if I'm wrong. I'm basing a E.R.P. on directory structure.

Answer (score 25):

Try using [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to print it in human-readable form.

Answer (score 18):

```
foreach($results['data'] as $result) {
    echo $result['type'], '<br />';
}
```

or `echo $results['data'][1]['type'];`

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you tell me how can I echo for example only the type of the Array [1] ?

Comment: what do you mean by Array [1]? :o

Comment: @andreas I want to echo only the COMMUNITY or the 163703342377960. Not the entire content of the array but specifically

Comment: Try `echo $results['data'][1]['page_id'];`

Answer (score 8):

You don’t have any need to use a *for* loop to see the data into the array. You can simply do it in the following manner:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use **var_dump()** function to display structured information about variables/expressions, including its type and value, or you can use **print_r()** to display information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans.

**Example:** Say we have got the following array, and we want to display its contents.

```
$arr = array ('xyz', false, true, 99, array('50'));
```

#### print_r() function - Displays human-readable output

```
Array
(
    [0] => xyz
    [1] =>
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 99
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
        )
)
```

#### var_dump() function - Displays values and types

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "xyz"
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
  [2]=>
  bool(true)
  [3]=>
  int(100)
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "50"
  }
}
```

The functions used in this answer can be found on the PHP documentation website, [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [print_r()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

For more details:

- [How to display PHP variable values with echo, print_r, and var_dump](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-display-php-variable-values-with-echo-print_r-and-var_dump/)
- *[How can I echo an array in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php/)*

Answer (score 8):

Human-readable (for example, can be logged to a text file...):

```
print_r($arr_name, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a parsable PHP representation, you could use:

```
$parseablePhpCode = var_export($yourVariable,true);
```

If you echo the exported code to a *file.php* (with a return statement) you may require it as

```
$yourVariable = require('file.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

I checked the answers, however, (for each) in PHP it is deprecated and no longer works with the latest PHP versions.

Usually, we would convert an array into a string to log it somewhere, perhaps debugging, test, etc.

I would convert the array into a string by doing:

```
$Output = implode(",", $SourceArray);
```

Whereas:

$output is the result (where the string would be generated

",": is the separator (between each array field).

$SourceArray: is your source array.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need echo 'type' field, you can use function '**array_column**' like:

```
$arr = $your_array;
echo var_dump(array_column($arr['data'], 'type'));
```

Answer (score -3):

Loop through and print all the values of an associative array, You could use a `foreach` loop, like this:

```
foreach($results as $x => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```