# 'Notice: Array to string conversion in...' error

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP file that tries to echo a `$_POST` and I get an error, here is the code:

```
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
for($i=0; $i<5;$i++){
    echo "<input name='C[]' value='$Texting[$i]' " . 
         "style='background-color:#D0A9F5;'></input>";

}
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
echo '<input type="submit" value="Save The Table" name="G"></input>'
```

Here is the code to echo the POST.

```
if(!empty($_POST['G'])){
    echo $_POST['C'];
}
```

But when the code runs I get an error like:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHIS\FinalSubmissionOfTheFormPHP.php on line 8
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which one is line 8? Is `$Texting[i]` a typo? Shouldn't that be `$Texting[$i]` instead?

Comment: Please show `var_dump($Texting)`.

Comment: Hi... Line 8 means, echo $_POST['C']. And var_dump($_POST['C']) is 
Arrayarray(3) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(4) "Male" [2]=> string(6) "Female" }. And var_dump($Texting) is array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(4) "Male" [2]=> string(6) "Female" } ...

Comment: "[How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/90527)", "[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/90527)"

Comment: Relevant: [How can I echo or print an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9816889/2943403)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The error means you are trying to use an *array* as though it's a *string*.

For example,

```
$var = [42];
echo "The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life is $var";
```

will cause this error. To avoid that, you have to address a specific array item, for example

```
echo "The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life is $var[0]";
```

The same goes for nested arrays. When you have many HTML inputs named `C[]` what you get in the POST array on the other end is an array of these values in `$_POST['C']`. So when you `echo` that, you are trying to print an array, so all it does is print `Array` and a notice.

To print properly an array, you either loop through it and `echo` each element, or you can use `print_r`.

Alternatively, if you don't know if it's an array or a string or whatever, you can use `var_dump($var)` which will tell you what type it is and what it's content is. Use that for debugging purposes only.

Answer (score 107):

### **What the PHP Notice means and how to reproduce it:**

If you send a PHP array into a function that expects a string like: `echo` or `print`, then the PHP interpreter will convert your array to the literal string `Array`, throw this Notice and keep going.  For example:

```
php> print(array(1,2,3))

PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpsh/phpsh.php(591) :
eval()'d code on line 1
Array
```

In this case, the function `print` dumps the literal string: `Array` to stdout and then logs the Notice to stderr and keeps going.

**Another example in a PHP script:**

```
<?php
    $stuff = array(1,2,3);
    print $stuff;  //PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in yourfile on line 3
?>
```

### Correction 1: use foreach loop to access array elements

http://php.net/foreach

```
$stuff = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($stuff as $value) {
    echo $value, "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
```

Or along with array keys

```
$stuff = array('name' => 'Joe', 'email' => 'joe@example.com');
foreach ($stuff as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
name: Joe
email: joe@example.com
```

Note that array elements could be arrays as well. In this case either use `foreach` again or access this inner array elements using array syntax, e.g. `$row['name']`

### Correction 2: Joining all the cells in the array together:

In case it's just a plain 1-demensional array, you can simply join all the cells into a string using a delimiter:

```
<?php
    $stuff = array(1,2,3);
    print implode(", ", $stuff);    //prints 1, 2, 3
    print join(',', $stuff);        //prints 1,2,3
```

### Correction 3: Stringify an array with complex structure:

In case your array has a complex structure but you need to convert it to a string anyway, then use http://php.net/json_encode

```
$stuff = array('name' => 'Joe', 'email' => 'joe@example.com');
print json_encode($stuff);
```

Prints

```
{"name":"Joe","email":"joe@example.com"}
```

### A quick peek into array structure: use the builtin php functions

If you want just to inspect the array contents for the debugging purpose, use one of the following functions. Keep in mind that var_dump is most informative of them and thus usually being preferred for the purpose

- http://php.net/print_r
- http://php.net/var_dump
- http://php.net/var_export

examples

```
$stuff = array(1,2,3);
print_r($stuff);
$stuff = array(3,4,5);
var_dump($stuff);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Helped me immensely.

I also had to use json_encode with this answer. 

print_r ( json_encode ( $AuthData ) );

Result similar to this: 
[{"system_id":"61a694d0-3605-4502-952b-38d87b451a56","system_auth_id":"caa5906f-d9ae-4297-8e9f-5ea8d9ed8b51","system_lastauth_id":"ace681bb-48f5-4831-a23d-6608c696f264","system_rundate":"2019-04-27T22:46:07.090Z"}]

Comment: Given this question is used as a canonical duplicate, I took the liberty to add some practical examples, as simply dumping the array contents is seldom being a goal.

Answer (score 7):

You are using `<input name='C[]'` in your HTML. This creates an array in PHP when the form is sent.

You are using `echo $_POST['C'];` to echo that array - this will not work, but instead emit that notice and the word "Array".

Depending on what you did with the rest of the code, you should probably use `echo $_POST['C'][0];`

Answer (score 6):

`Array to string conversion` in latest versions of php 7.x is error, rather than notice, and prevents further code execution.

Using `print`, `echo` on array is not an option anymore.

Suppressing errors and notices is not a good practice, especially when in development environment and still debugging code.

Use `var_dump`,`print_r`, iterate through input value using `foreach` or `for` to output input data for names that are declared as input arrays ('`name[]`')

Most common practice to catch errors is using `try/catch` blocks, that helps us prevent interruption of code execution that might cause possible errors wrapped within `try` block.

```
  try{  //wrap around possible cause of error or notice
    
    if(!empty($_POST['C'])){
        echo $_POST['C'];
    }

  }catch(Exception $e){

    //handle the error message $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: That would be a **very** bad idea. there is nothing to "handle" in this error. It must be **fixed** right away. Adding a try catch makes absolutely no sense here.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST['C']);
$result = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

if you want to capture the result in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['G']) && isset($_POST['c']){
        for($i=0; $i< count($_POST['C']); $i++){
            echo $_POST['C'][$i];
        }
}
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['G'])` doesn't appear to be relevant in this context.  Maybe `!empty()` would be a logical choice.  This answer is missing its educational explantion.

Answer (score 0):

this error happened to me in the following context:
I was trying to do a mass allocation registration

```
Product::create($request->all());
```

I got the error right there, what was happening is that my model had the variable $table misspelled:

```
protected $table = ['product'];
```

As it should be:

```
protected $table = 'product';
```

I know it's something very specific, but I hope it helps someone.