# Displaying multiple URL links from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Like the titles describes, I'm trying to output multiple URL links from a database. But recieving an error.

**PHP**

```
$link_select = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM links WHERE sigaren_id = " .$resultaat_fetch_id_sigaren);                  
while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($link_select)) 
{
    $resultaat_link = $link['link'];
    $link .= "<a href='".$link."'>$link</a>";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<b>Links</b><br><br>
<?php echo $link;  ?>
```

**ERROR**

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

Comment: `$link = mysql_fetch_ARRAY($link_select)`. You are trying to append a string with an array, bruv. As a matter of fact, you are also trying to append an array with a string. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: Your code is very messy. You're `echo`ing an array, your `Notice` just said that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve error 'Notice: Array to string conversion in.....'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017409/how-to-solve-error-notice-array-to-string-conversion-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, you're treating an array as a string.

`$link` is an array, but you're referring to it as a string.

To fix it, change the code like this:

```
$link_select = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM links WHERE sigaren_id = " .$resultaat_fetch_id_sigaren);                  
while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($link_select)) 
{
    $resultaat_link = $link['link'];
    $linkData .= "<a href='".$resultaat_link."'>$resultaat_link</a>";
}   

<b>Links</b><br><br>
<?php echo $linkData;  ?>
```

Side note: Stop using mysql_* functions because they are deprecated. Move on to PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: Well, seems like your code still treats `$link` as string, since you're still concatenating stuff in there with `.=`

Comment: Ooh stupid me... --' I used the $link variable 2 times.. my bad. 
Thanks for clearing that out!

Comment: Why do I get http://localhost/<hostname>/www.google.com when I press the link? <hostname> = my website name. 
Instead I want it to go to www.google.com directly.

Comment: It depends on what output you got. Please open up another question for that with your output, etc.

Comment: When I press a link => http://localhost/el_gusto/www.google.be is filled in the browser.

Comment: Oh, I see. You have to do this:

`$linkData .= "<a href='http://".$resultaat_link."'>$resultaat_link</a>";`

Comment: Awesome! that did it again!