# Pass Multi Values to PHP Variable and set this value to HTML input field

Tags: php, html, arrays

this is my input filed which I'm using

### [image: HTML input field]

This is how I am print my variable

### [image: print values]

getting this error

> Array ( [0] => 
>   Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendance-system\view-all-latecomers.php on line 162
>   Array )

Any Solution please helped me. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve PHP error 'Notice: Array to string conversion in...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017409/how-to-solve-php-error-notice-array-to-string-conversion-in)

Comment: Remove the images and copy paste the code instead

Answer (score 0):

When you add `[]` to the end of an input name, that causes all the values of those inputs to be put into an array in PHP. So `$_POST['checked_id']` is an array, not a string. Then when you do:

```
value="<?= $_POST['checked_id'] ?>"
```

you're trying to echo the entire array into that one input. You can't echo an array, so you get that warning.

If this is part of a loop, you need to index the array

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['checked_id']); $i++) { ?>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="checked_id[]" value="<?=$_POST['checked_id'][$i]?>">
    ...
    <?php
}
```

Comment: if I only checked 1 value from all check boxes then? @barmar

Comment: This isn't a checkbox, it's a hidden input. They all get submitted.