# check if all items of an array are available in another associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays as given below. I want to check if all items of first array `$arrayA` are available in `$arrayB` against key `fruit`. How I can do that?

```
<?php
$arrayA = ['apple', 'guava'];
$arrayB = [
            ['fruit' => 'apple','vegetables' => 'potato'],
            ['fruit' => 'guava','vegetables' => 'onion']
          ];

 $containsSearch = count(array_intersect($arrayA, $arrayB)) == count($arrayA);

 var_dump($containsSearch);
```

Above code returns error:

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/test/b.php on line 8

Comment: Here it returns bool(false)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve PHP error 'Notice: Array to string conversion in...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017409/how-to-solve-php-error-notice-array-to-string-conversion-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) as you only want to use the `fruit` key. This should then be:

```
// array_column($arrayB, 'fruit') instead of $arrayB
$containsSearch = count(array_intersect($arrayA, array_column($arrayB, 'fruit'))) == count($arrayA);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_column()` is a necessary step to isolate the `fruit` elements.  `count()` calls are not necessary because the filtered `$arrayA` will be ordered the same as the unfiltered `$arrayA` so you can check them identically.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/95bf54b8016c29e08bc82e3d2daa168bb49bddbf))

```
$arrayA = ['apple', 'guava'];
$arrayB = [
            ['fruit' => 'apple','vegetables' => 'potato'],
            ['fruit' => 'guava','vegetables' => 'onion']
          ];
var_export(array_intersect($arrayA, array_column($arrayB, 'fruit')) === $arrayA);
```

Output:

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $diff = array_diff($arrayA, array_column($arrayB,'fruit'));
    if(count($diff) == 0){
        echo 'all items of first array $arrayA are available in $arrayB against key fruit';
    } else print_r($diff);
```