# Wordpress Array to string conversion in functions.php on line 194

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem. I work on wordpress and i have an error message :

> Array to string conversion in functions.php on line 194.

I'm sorry for my bad english i'm french user.

```
    if ( !empty( $entry_taxonomies ) ){ 
        $htmltext .= '<div class="entry-meta">' ;
        foreach ( $entry_taxonomies as $tax_id => $entry_tax ){ 
            if($option == 'around' and ($entry_tax['text'] == 'Ville' or 
                $entry_tax['text'] == 'Département' or 
                $entry_tax['text'] == 'Code Postal' )) { 
                hybrid_post_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_id, 'text' => '<span class="term-name">Même ' . strtolower($entry_tax['text']) . ':</span>' . ' %s' ) );
            } 
            if($option == 'keywords' and $entry_tax['text'] == 'Mots Clefs') {
                $htmltext .= wp_get_post_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_id, 'text' => '<span class="term-name"><strong>' . $entry_tax['text'] . ':</strong></span><br>' . ' %s' ) );
            } 
        }//end foreach 
        $htmltext .= '</div>' ;

    } //end empty check
    return ($htmltext) ;
}
```

Comment: And which line is 194?

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017409/how-to-solve-php-error-notice-array-to-string-conversion-in/20017469](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017409/how-to-solve-php-error-notice-array-to-string-conversion-in/20017469)