# In php, how do I fix an array to string conversion error in my code (specifically this line- echo " - $msg<br>" ;?

Tags: php, arrays, string

This is my code that is returning a error: Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cim/msgboard/login.php on line 29 (echo " - $msg
" ;)

- Array

  ```
    <?php
            include('includes/header_login.inc') ;
            if (isset($errors) && !empty($errors)) {
            echo '<p id="err_msg">A problem has occurred:<br>' ;
            foreach($errors as $msg) {
            echo " - $msg<br>" ;
            }
           echo 'please try again or <a href="registration-page.php">Register</a></p>' ;  
    }
    ?>
  ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40049279/11430357

Comment: $msg is an array and echo cannot print arrays directly. That's why you're getting the error message. You have to use var_dump($msg) or print_r($msg) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to print message like `$msg['message']` and if you want to add some HTML in your PHP it should be like:

```
echo "- ".$msg['message']."<br>";
```

When you `$msg` in `"` here  `"`, print will like:

> -$msg.

PHP can not understand the variable in the echo so you should close the quotes.