# How to echo an array

Tags: php, html, echo

It's not like I've never done it before, but for some reason it won't work this time... I'm just returnin an array from a function

```
//Call Function to create the result array
$specs = giveData();
```

and I'm trying to output the data with echo this way:

```
<b>lenght:</b><?php echo $specs[0]['lenght']; ?>
```

I already tried var_dump and it shows me the data in the array, also with print_r works.

EDIT: I updated the code the way it works for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're spelling the key  correctly?

Comment: You can't echo an "array" but you can echo the value of a key in an array. Paste the value of var_dump($specs) so we can verify the key you are using is correct.

Comment: Google's banned in your country too?

Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php

Comment: I posted a link to the picture in my first entry

Answer (score 1):

Print all values of an array

```
<?php
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($specs);
   // OR var_dump to get variable type (string / int / etc)
   var_dump($specs);
   echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The echo of the `pre` tags are for formatting reasons in HTML since the `pre` tag will show linebreaks (\n) as a visible new line inside of HTML.

As for echoing a single value from an array, all you have to do is refernce the key like you were doing.

```
echo $specs['length'];
```

You can make sure the key exists by using the function `isset`.

```
if(isset($specs['length'])) {
   echo $specs['length'];
}else{
   echo 'Error, Length not found';
}
```

The functions used in this answer can be found on the PHP.net website [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), [print_r()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you want the number of elements of the array :

```
echo count($specs);
```

or iterate over your array :

```
foreach($specs as $key => $value){
    echo "$key : $value<br/>";
}
```

Comment: should be `echo count($specs);` length() function doesn't exist in PHP

Comment: @cnlevy I was certainly very tired when I wrote that. Thanks.