# echo PHP array to see its properties/values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm querying a database through php and trying to store the result as a php array.

But when I echo $results and call the file in my browser, I just see "Array"

How can I see the results/whats inside of the array?

```
//find data as an associative array
$results = ORM::for_table('table_name')
            ->where('slug', 'slug_name')
            ->where('date', DATE>='2000-01-01')
            ->where('data', DATA)
            ->find_array();

echo $results
```

Comment: `var_dump($results)` or `print_r($results)`

Comment: @JohnConde or `var_export($results)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to echo an array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php)

Comment: maybe interesting...  [A more pretty/informative Var_dump alternative in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141585/a-more-pretty-informative-var-dump-alternative-in-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value of an array element can be another array, multidimensional, using the foreach shows each bucket contains the associative buckets slug, date, data

```
foreach($results as $result) {
 echo $result['slug'], '<br>';
 echo $result['date'], '<br>';
echo $result['data'], '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Please add a description for your code, we try to avoid code-only answers

Answer (score 1):

use `print_r($results)` or `var_dump($results)`

Better approach to view on the browser would be

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($results) . "</pre>";
```

or

```
echo "<pre>" . var_dump($results) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to create a more readable dump.

```
function debug($v) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($v);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```