# PHP is_object() seems not work properly

Tags: php, arrays, object, recursion, printing

I have:

```
<?php

function _dump($var, $name = "", $return = false){
    $output = "<div>";
    if (!is_array($var) && !is_object($var)) {
        $output .= 'Var name: '.$name.'<br>';
        $output .= 'Type: '.gettype($var).'<br>';
        $output .= 'Length: '. strlen((string) $var).'<br>';
        $output .= 'Value: '.$var.'<br>';
    } else{
        $output .= 'Var '.$name.' is an '.gettype($var).
        ' with length '.count((array) $var).
        ' and the values is listed bellow:<br>';

        foreach($var as $k => $v){
            $output .= '<div style="margin-left:10px;">'.
            _dump($v, $k, true).'</div>';
        }
    }

    $output .= "</div>";

    if($return)
        return $output;
    else echo $output;
}


$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
foreach($backtrace as $b){
    _dump($b['args'], "Args");
    echo '<hr>';
}
?>
```

When **$var** is an array it prints the array values as expected, but raises a Notice: **"array to string conversion on line 8"**. And when within **$var**($b['args']) there is objects it raises Fatal Error: **"Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string on line 8"**.

The issue, i think, is not the "__PHP_Incomplete_Class" thing but the "could not be converted to string on line 8", because i am already doing **"if(!is_array() && !is_object())"**. So, if i am checking it, why is this raising notices and errors?

Any ideas?

This is the exact iteration from **debug_bactrace()** that is raising exceptions:

```
Array
    (
        [file] => /home/gabriel/Projects/realinvest/engine/class.system.php
        [line] => 93
        [function] => call_user_func_array
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
                            (
                                [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Procedures
                                [system:protected] => System Object
                                    (
                                        [controller:protected] => users
                                        [method:protected] => register
                                        [args:protected] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 1
                                            )

                                        [cpath:protected] => /var/www/html/realinvest//controllers/
                                    )

                                [module:Controller:private] => procedures
                                [method:Controller:private] => register
                                [model:protected] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
                                    (
                                        [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => ModelProcedures
                                        [primarykey:Model:private] => id
                                        [table:Model:private] => procedures
                                        [dbclass:protected] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
                                            (
                                                [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Dbclass
                                                [dbhost:Dbclass:private] => localhost
                                                [dbname:Dbclass:private] => processos_real
                                                [dbuser:Dbclass:private] => root
                                                [dbpass:Dbclass:private] => h7t846m2
                                                [dbtype:Dbclass:private] => mysql
                                                [cnnInfo:Dbclass:private] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [info] => No connection info.
                                                    )

                                                [connection:Dbclass:private] => 
                                                [queryerror] => 
                                                [datatypes:Dbclass:private] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [boolean] => 5
                                                        [integer] => 1
                                                        [double] => 2
                                                        [string] => 2
                                                        [resource] => 3
                                                    )

                                                [transaction_mode:Dbclass:private] => 
                                                [lastresult:Dbclass:private] => 
                                                [error] => 0
                                            )

                                        [sql:protected] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
                                            (
                                                [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Sql
                                                [table:Sql:private] => procedures
                                                [sqlstring:Sql:private] => SELECT * FROM `procedures` WHERE procedures.`id`= ? 
                                                [sqlvalues:Sql:private] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 1
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => register
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of `$var` in order to test it?

Comment: Notice are just here to raise awareness. It's non-blocking for you code and will be disabled on production server. On object, you should use the [``get_class()``](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.get-class.php) function in order to display its name.

Comment: Give us the complete error message and tell us which line it refers to. Sure that `echo $k.' => '.$v` doesn't raise that error…‽

Comment: @deceze Absolutely sure, cause it points the line in which the error occurred.

Comment: I read on a [blog post](http://www.phpini.in/php/php-incomplete-class-object.html) that we can have similar issue when using `session_start` before declaring a class. Are you doing something like this?

Comment: And which line is that exactly?

Comment: @deceze In this pseudo-code example it would be exactly line 5.

Comment: @AnthonyB I will search for this "session_start()" issue. Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielGuelfi This issue happens when we try to save in session an object of a class before declaring it. So the class in session is not declared and PHP can't deserialize it.

Comment: @AnthonyB It is not the case. I didn't tried to save the object in session.

Comment: @GabrielGuelfi Are you using any serialization? According to the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) this error usually occurs when unserialization failed.

Comment: @GabrielGuelfi what do you want the output to be ?

Comment: @AnthonyB nope. I am building a Krumo like tool to debug code. I simply call foo($var) and it does something pretty much alike this example. No serialization, no session, nothing. I don't understand why it is raising error even with the is_object check.

Comment: I changed the input example to the one that is raising exceptions. It has some issues like returns from call_user_func_array and class loading from ReflectionClass instances. Perhaps this elucidate something that we're missing.

Comment: And if somebody vote me down, please let me know why, cause a simple down vote does not help anybody at all.

Comment: Note that you miss a bracket in your code. Try open one just after the deepest `else`

Comment: @GabrielGuelfi can we see your $var initialization (before error so)? I can't reproduce your error with any array/object or anything.

Comment: Morning @AnthonyB! $var is an iteration from debug_backtrace(): $backtrace = debug_backtrace(); foreach($backtrace as $b){foo($b['args']); } 

And i realized that it raises error when there is objects among the arguments on $b['args'] array.

Comment: I updated code including all the info and making it even more similar to the original one.

Comment: Your code is easier to understand with this example, thanks @GabrielGuelfi! It does not print anything for me; but I'll search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized the solution with a hint from a fellow dev.

I was right in thinking that the problem was the "is_object()" function.

Actually, there are some cases, when $var datatype can be an object, but is_object() returns false. It happens when the object is not serializable.

So i solved changing:

```
if(!is_array($var) && !is_object($var)){...
```

for:

```
if(!is_array($var) && gettype($var) !== "object"){...
```

So the exceptions disappeared and the script could go on.

A simple but unknown and annoying detail about "is_object()" php function.

Hope it helps someone who is facing trouble with this confusing thing about is_object().

Answer (score 0):

Whether this is an array or an object, your code is trying to echo the key and value foreach key/value that exists.  Since this is a multidimensional array you won't be able to `echo $v` for every value.

Instead you could try `print_r` or `var_dump`:

```
foreach((array) $var as $k => $v){
    echo $k.' => '.print_r($v);
}
```

See more here regarding how print an array: [How to echo an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php)

Comment: With his problem, even var_dump or print_r should dis^may the error about incomplete class, no?

Comment: It's an array, not sure why he would convert it to be an object

Comment: @Dan I corrected the example code. It has a recursion for the case $v is an array or object.

Comment: @Dan i meant that i corrected the example code in this post to be similar the original one.