# Php array not working. whats wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I want to work with api.

Here is my code:

```
// create a new purchase bill
$purchase = $parasut->make('sale')->create(array (
    'description'    => $siparis,
    'invoice_id'     => null,
    'invoice_series' => null,
    'currency'       => 'TRL',
    'item_type'      => 'invoice',
    'issue_date'     => $order_date_created,
    'due_date'       => $order_date_created,
    'contact_id'     => $contactToken,
    'category_id'    => null,
    'archived'       => false,
    'billing_address' => $user_address,
    'billing_fax'   => null,
    'billing_phone' => $user_phone,
    'details_attributes' => array (
        $parasut->make('product')->getProductFromOrder(), // the products
    ),
));
```

Here is  getProductFromOrder() function:

```
public function getProductFromOrder()
{
    $sku = array(5542003,5542004);
    $qty = array("3","1");
    $total = array("11.29","12.00");

    for($i=0; $i<count($sku); $i++){
        $urunler[$i] = array(
                    'product_id'     => $sku[$i], // the products
                    'quantity'       => '3',
                    'unit_price'     => '12.99',
                    'vat_rate'       => '18',
                    'discount_type'  => 'amount',
                    'discount_value' => '0',
            );
        print ($urunler[$i]);
    }
}
```

Its not working. When i run the first code, products not showing. Where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Try `print_r($products[$i]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function `getProductFromOrder()`  to this instead:

```
public function getProductFromOrder()
{
    $sku = array(5542003,5542004);
    $qty = array("3","1");
    $total = array("11.29","12.00");

    for($i=0; $i<count($sku); $i++){
        $urunler[$i] = array(
                    'product_id'     => $sku[$i], // the products
                    'quantity'       => '3',
                    'unit_price'     => '12.99',
                    'vat_rate'       => '18',
                    'discount_type'  => 'amount',
                    'discount_value' => '0',
            );
    }
    return $urunler;
}
```

Use `return` instead of `print` and write the `return` outside the `for` loop.