# Printing Arrays PHP Javascript

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code.php:

```
$info = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'num' => 1,
    'name' => '15 TV',
    'stream_type' => 'live',
    'stream_id' => 219,
    'stream_icon' => 'https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/5d/2f/1c/5d2f1cb1-3a21-71ff-c10c-e27253ba13dc/source/512x512bb.jpg',
    'epg_channel_id' => NULL,
    'added' => '1535765481',
    'category_id' => '3',
    'custom_sid' => '',
    'tv_archive' => 0,
    'direct_source' => '',
    'tv_archive_duration' => 0,
  ),
  479 =>
  array (
    'num' => 125,
    'name' => 'LA DOS',
    'stream_type' => 'live',
    'stream_id' => 323,
    'stream_icon' => 'http://www.dazplayer.com/img_chh/la_dos_espa%C3%B1a.png',
    'epg_channel_id' => NULL,
    'added' => '1535838540',
    'category_id' => '13',
    'custom_sid' => '',
    'tv_archive' => 0,
    'direct_source' => '',
    'tv_archive_duration' => 0,
  ),
);
```

I have these array and I want to print it, the arrays go to the number 0 from 479. I tried to use the code that it is below but it is not working as well as I want, because it is not printing the right variables. I know that I have to use a loop and the command line for each but I could not be able to do it work.
The variables that I am interested in are:

> name
>
> stream_id
>
> stream_icon
>
> category_id

```
  <?php
  foreach($info as $x => $x_value) {
   echo "Name=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
   echo "<br>;";
  }
 ?>
```

If someone could help me fixing the bug, i will be thankful.
Regards, Dix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this way with `foreach()` loop as **$key=>$value** pattern. To get values you've to use `$value['field_name_for_that_you_need_value']`. For example: `$x_value['name']` to get the value of **name** field

```
<?php
  foreach($info as $x => $x_value) {
   echo "Name=" . $x_value['name'] . ", Stream Id=" . $x_value['stream_id'].", Stream Icon=".$x_value['stream_icon']. "Category Id=". $x_value['category_id'];
   echo "<br>;";
  }
 ?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/cvTsc

Comment: Can you please post the reason for voting it down?

Comment: sorry - i downvoted this because the question is a duplicate but after reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions) I think I was wrong to do so.  your answer is fine but this question has been asked a thousand times here on SO.

Comment: Hi Smart-Googler, thanks for your help. I did not vote it down any answer that they gave me, all the answers were useful for me.

Comment: @billynoah I really appreciate your clear confess mate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method:

```
print_r($info);
```

Which will be in your context:

```
foreach($info as $key => $value)
{
  echo "Name=" . $key . ", Value=" . print_r($value, true);
  echo "<br>";
}
```

[Documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: you can't concat `print_r()` like that

Comment: it should be `print_r($value, true)` - in order the make it return.