# How to use echo with PHP's array_reverse() Function

Tags: php

I'm not a big fan of using print_r and I prefer to use echo all the time when I can so how can I use echo with PHPs array_reverse() function

This how the docs look like most of the time online they use print_r all the time for example

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"Volvo","b"=>"BMW","c"=>"Toyota");
print_r(array_reverse($a));
?>
```

I tried to use echo with this example but it does not work with echo.

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"Volvo","b"=>"BMW","c"=>"Toyota");
echo array_reverse($a);
?>
```

So how can I get it to work with echo?

Comment: What do you expect to see as a result? `echo` can only print _strings_ (or types that can be implicitly casted to a string).

Comment: You can't, at least it won't produce what you expect. `echo` can only output _scalar_ values, but you have a structured value. So you'd need to implement a wrapper around `echo` that converts the structure into scalar values, that in a recursive manner.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/t1dSN - you really want to pick `var_dump` of these options.

Comment: Not sure how `array_reverse()` has any effect on the use of `echo` - it's more to do with `echo` and arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. You can join all the array elements in a string using the [implode](http://php.net/implode) function, then echo it out.

```
<?php

$a=array("a"=>"Volvo","b"=>"BMW","c"=>"Toyota");

$comma_separated = implode(", ", array_reverse($a));

echo $comma_separated;

?>
```

I've separated each array element by a comma.

Alternatively, for more control over the results, you can simply loop through the array using `foreach`, you can get an idea of how to do this here: [How to echo an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php)

Comment: OMG thank you :) this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an array to `echo`; you have to traverse it and echo keys and/or values.

For a single level associative array like the one in the example this can be done like this:

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"Volvo","b"=>"BMW","c"=>"Toyota");

foreach( array_reverse( $a ) as $key => $value ) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

The output:

```
c: Toyota
b: BMW
a: Volvo
```

You may adjust the above code to format the output as you like.

Of course it won't work if the array contains other (nested) arrays or objects.

---

However if your need is for **debugging** purposes I suggest to stick with PHP's native functions available for that specific purpose:

[**print_r**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

[**var_export**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

[**var_dump**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: You don't need the intermediate assignment either: `foreach(array_reverse($a) as $k=>$v)`

Comment: @Progrock yes, you're right; Thank you