# How do I print out "id" in this array?

Tags: php, arrays

This question might have been asked earlier. I will appreciate an answer as well as a guide to previously asked questions if they exist.

```
array:3 [▼
"027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da" => array:9 [▼
"rowId" => "027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da"
"id" => "1"
"name" => "ks"
"qty" => "2"
"price" => 500.0
"options" => []
"tax" => "105.00"
"isSaved" => false
"subtotal" => "1000.00"
]
"370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df" => array:9 [▼
"rowId" => "370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df"
"id" => "2"
"name" => "clear glass"
"qty" => "2"
"price" => 500.0
"options" => []
"tax" => "105.00"
"isSaved" => false
"subtotal" => "1000.00"
]

"efb26e2c6ab6bd4d1323288923522d4e" => array:9 [▼
"rowId" => "efb26e2c6ab6bd4d1323288923522d4e"
"id" => "4"
"name" => "Double wall glass"
"qty" => 1
"price" => 34.0
"options" => []
"tax" => "7.14"
"isSaved" => false
"subtotal" => "34.00"
]
]
```

How do I print id , name, qty...?

Comment: just read php documentation. `echo $array['id'];` etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to echo or print an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-or-print-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about multidimensional array in the doc.
Here is a hint :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['id'].'<br/>';
}
```