# how to print an array on the screen PHP

Tags: php

Good Morning,

I have this piece of code:

```
$contenitoreArray = ["Ottimo Lavoro", "Ora", "Tu Puoi",["Inviare",["La tua","Casa"]]];
$fraseFinale = "";
function ricorsione($contenitoreArray) {
   foreach($contenitoreArray as $valoreArray){
    if(is_array($valoreArray)){
        ricorsione($valoreArray);
    }else{
        $fraseFinale .= $valoreArray;
    }
   }
    return $fraseFinale;
}

$peppe = ricorsione($contenitoreArray); 
echo $peppe;
```

My goal is to be able to print the entire array on the screen

thank you very much for your availability

Comment: i edited bad word :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to echo or print an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-or-print-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can simplify the code:

```
$contenitoreArray = ["Ottimo Lavoro", "Ora", "Tu Puoi",["Inviare",["La tua","Casa"]]];
$fraseFinale = [];

// flatten the array to one dimension
array_walk_recursive($contenitoreArray, function ($v) use (&$fraseFinale) { $fraseFinale[] = $v; });
// next - just implode with the required glue parameter
echo implode(', ', $fraseFinale);
```

More ways to flatten the array are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array).

Comment: thanks thanks thanks thanks grazie grazie grazie grazie grazie