# auto formatter for nested arrays, objects output

Tags: php

Trying to study some outputs of arrays and object by using for example `print_r($wp_query);` but it's really hard to read it, i have searched but what I found does not format well nested arrays, I wonder if there is a solution for this? Thank you

Comment: You can use `<pre>` tag. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-or-print-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [VarDumper component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html). It could be used as a standalone and easily improve your array or object output.

```
composer require --dev symfony/var-dumper


<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$array = [
    [
        [
            [
                [
                    'some_key' => 'some_value',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

dump($array);
```

The output would be the following.

```
^ array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    0 => array:1 [
      0 => array:1 [
        0 => array:1 [
          "some_key" => "some_value"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```