# Reading from a .txt file - concatenate - echoing content puts a space in automatically?

Tags: php, html

I'm reading content from a text file which I'm showing on a page later, this is my code:

```
$lines = file("content.txt");
$i=1;
foreach($lines  as $line ){

$var["line" . $i] = $line;
$i++;
}
extract($var);
```

The text file includes content in this format:

```
bla1
bla2
```

and so on, there's no space behind the domains just a linebreak, now I want to concatenate the content and show it, so I do this:

```
$as1 = $line1.$line2;
echo $as1;
```

But instead of the expected result

```
Bla1Bla2
```

I get

```
Bla1 Bla2
```

What am I doing wrong ? I can assure that there's no space in the text file not behind nor infront of the content.

Comment: The browser renders newlines (`\n`) as spaces. Look into the source and you see it's still in a new line.

Comment: for more explanation see the link 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no space; but unless you tell the file() function otherwise, there is a line feed at the end of each line

```
$lines = file("content.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

A browser will render a line feed as a space, unless inside a  or  block

Answer (score 0):

use `trim` for this situation

```
$as1 = trim($line1).trim($line2);
echo $as1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try trimming your input...

```
$lines = file("content.txt");
$i=1;
foreach($lines  as $line ){

$var["line" . $i] = trim($line);
$i++;
}
extract($var);
```