# Why is there a space?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put some links at the top of my site on the right side but when I do this I get a small about ten pixel space between  them. Can someone please explain what is going wrong with it.

Html:

```
<div id="socialLinks">
     <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
     <a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#socialLinks{
    /* Positioning */
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:right;   
}

#socialLinks a{
    /* Sizing */
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;

    /* Decoration */
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#9FD9FF;

    /* Font */
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:25px;

    /* Border */
    border-style:solid;
    border-right-style:none;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: remove the padding-right and padding-left directive inside the css

Comment: padding-right + padding-left = 5+5 = 10px

Comment: JSFiddle for anyone to use: http://jsfiddle.net/7Jw7M/

Removing padding does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Mike was right, changing the padding to 0 and removing doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers like to condense all whitespace into a single space when rendering (view this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space) question for more information). This is caused by the browser, not by your stylesheet. This is a property of HTML in which new lines are to be treated as spaces.

To remedy the issue, you can place all of your `<a>` tags on the same line, however the code won't look very clean (as shown on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Jw7M/1/))

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
```

to

```
padding-right:0;
padding-left:0;
```

or if padding isn't being set elsewhere, just remove the lines entirely.

EDIT: @j08691 is right, this didn't work at all. It's the whitespace between the two `a` tags. Answer left unedited for your downvoting pleasure.

Comment: To whomever upvoted this, test it...it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hQakr/