# Margin, border, padding and size don't add up as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a simple scenario of basic `HTML` and `CSS` for which the bounding box measurements don't add up width-wise.

The expected result is obtained by setting the column width to `324 px` although `320 px` seems to be the proper fit. In the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mWqL/) there's a single property value to alter to see the expected result v.s. the desired width.

**Expected result (wrong property value)**

```
div.container div.column {
    width: 324px;
}
```

**Bad result (desired property value)**

```
div.container div.column {
    width: 320px;
}
```

**Why I think `320 px` should be the containing width of my two buttons:**

`320 px` (*column*) =  `155 px` (*button*) + `10px` (*margin*) + `155px` (*button*)

I'm sure the issue is on my side of comprehension, can anyone explain why this is going on?

Comment: You might want to also read up on this: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/boxmodel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<button>`s by default are inline-block elements. This means that the space (literally space) affects it's spacing.

You can set the button to display block and float to the left to get similar results:

```
div.container button {
    width: 155px;
    height: 155px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display:block; float:left;
}
```

also you'll need to clear your float in your row:

```
div.container div.row:after {
    clear:both;
    display:table;
    content:'';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mWqL/2/

Answer (score 1):

Because the two `<button>` tags are on separate lines it tries to add some kind of white-spacing in between the two items. If you put them on one line it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/4mWqL/1/

```
<div class="row">
   <button></button><button></button>
</div>
```

From [Why does the browser renders a newline as space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space)

> Browsers condense multiple whitespace characters (including newlines)
>   to a single space when rendering. The only exception is within 
>   elements or those that have the CSS property white-space: pre set. (Or
>   in XHTML, the xml:space="preserve" attribute.)