# newlines character ignored by jsx table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a table with a multiline string, but the string is not formatted correctly by my table.  Here is the jsx:

```
<td>
  {arr.join('\n')}
</td>
```

And here is the corresponding html:

```
<td data-reactid=".xyz">Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4</td>
```

But in the browser it looks like:

[image]

What's going on and how do I get my newlines to appear?

Comment: If you are only asking for why (which you do at the moment at least), it's a duplicate of [Why does the browser renders a newline as space?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588356/218196).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've got a few options:

1) Use a block level element such as `div` or a `p` and wrap each line.

```
var TextLines = React.createClass({      
    render: function() {
        var lines = this.props.lines;

        var formatted = lines.map(function(line) {
            return (<p>{line}</p>);
        });
        return (<div>{ formatted }</div>);
    }
});

var lines = ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3'];
React.render(<TextLines lines={ lines }/>, 
              document.getElementById('container'));
```

2) Use a span with a `br` element:

```
var TextLines = React.createClass({      
    render: function() {
        var lines = this.props.lines;

        var br = lines.map(function(line) {
            return (<span>{line}<br/></span>);
        });
        return (<div>{ br }</div>);
    }
});

var lines = ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3'];
React.render(<TextLines lines={ lines } />,  
              document.getElementById('container'));
```

3) If you're certain there is no threat of XSS/hacks with the data, you could use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) with a 'br' for each line:

```
var TextLines = React.createClass({      
    render: function() {
        var lines = this.props.lines;
        var content = {
            __html: lines.join('<br />')
        };     
        return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ content } />);
    }
});

var lines = ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3'];
React.render(<TextLines lines={ lines } />, 
             document.getElementById('container'));
```

The last one produces the least amount of HTML, but at a cost of potentially risky the security of the web page/user. I wouldn't use this one if the others work for you.

Comment: Think it's worth adding a mention for the css `white-space` property here as per @Chris answer.

Answer (score 23):

Try `white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-wrap;` (Thanks, @Mirage) in the style of your cell.

```css
td {
  width: 150px;
}

.nopre {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.withpre {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  white-space: pre;
}

.withprewrap {
  background-color: orange;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<table><tr>

<td class="nopre">Line A
Line B
Line C
This is a cell with no whitespace setting</td>

</tr></table><table><tr>

<td class="withpre">Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
This is a cell with white-space: pre</td>

</tr></table><table><tr>
  
<td class="withprewrap">Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
This is a cell with white-space: pre-wrap</td>
  
</tr></table>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `white-space: pre` will preserve your newlines, but it causes your text to no longer wrap. This means, provided it's a long string of text, it will stretch outside of your element. For this reason I have found `white-space: pre-wrap` to work better for us.

Comment: If you don't want whitespace in your JSX, you can use `\u000A` as a linebreak. E.g. `<td>Line 1\u000ALine 2</td>`

Comment: this inserts a comma for me. not line break

Answer (score 15):

When you really need this, use `{'\n'}` inside your JSX.

Comment: This solution is here by default in React-Native. How does this work when you want the inner text surrounded by brackets (to adhere to the ESLint rule "react/jsx-no-literals")? I can't get it to work properly with template strings.

Answer (score 3):

try to use the `<pre>` element or the css property `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Comment: only adding <pre> adding space at the bottom of the text. The pre-wrap from other answer doesn't