# Why does jade ignore \n and white space?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, pug

I am generating a bit of Jade based HTML with `var generateCodeBlock = jade.compile('div !{text}', {pretty: true});`
I want to create something like this

```
<div>   
    var json = {
        labelA: 'a',
        labelB: 2
       };
</div>
```

but when I input `{text: 'var json = {\n    labelA: 'a',\n     labelB: 2\n    };'}` it ends up creating `<div class="setup">   var json = { labelA: 'a', labelB: 2 };</div>`. I have also tried using `#{text}` in `jade.compile`, but there was no difference. 
Why does jade flatten my variable input?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/9ucLk938/)

UPDATE: 
I have now tried creating a separate file for the template with

```
block codeBlock
    div.codeBlock
        for part in code
            div(class="#{part.className}") !{part.text}
```

and `jade.compileFile` and it is still producing `var json = { labelA: 'a', labelB: 2 };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jade does not ignore whitespace and newline. If you actually log what `jade.compile($("#jadehi").html())(djson)` returns you'll see that any whitespace or newlines you put in your data (like `"Jade\n Test                 Page"`) will still be there.

It's HTML (or, more accurately, how browsers interpret HTML) that ignores those characters. As explained in this question:

[Why does the browser renders a newline as space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space)

And, as suggested there, perhaps using a `<pre>` element will help you.