# How to hide space?

Tags: html, css

I need to add space between "who" and "we are". If I add space inside  it's delete in DOM.

```
<h2>
<span>who</span>
<br>we are
</h2>
```

I want to add this space, becouse in seo audits i have:

> whowe are

I want:

> who we are

Comment: Not sure, but try `<span>who </span>`. I added space after "who". Let me know if doesn't work. And yah remove the `<br>` tag for sure.

Comment: Have you tried putting both lines of text on one line with a space after the `</span>`?

Comment: What about a `&nbsp;`?

Comment: You have a page break in there, which causes the "we are" to fall to the next line. There's no way to get it looking how you want with that `br` there.

Comment: If there is really a space or even a newline between `</span>` and `<br>` then there will be a space between `who` and `we` because this is the default behavior. [Why does the browser renders a newline as space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356)

Comment: This is an artifact of whatever tool is generating your "seo audits"; it's not relevant to what's actually in the page (or how it's being indexed by search engines.)

Comment: who does this SEO audit? I think they are giving you the wrong info.

Comment: My first try would be to move the `<br>` to the end of the `<span>` rather than before the `we`. `<span>who</span><br>↵we are`. But I don't know which seo tool you mean either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for SEO and maybe accessibility (as well as using some browser related features like Mozilla Firefox reading mode, RSS Feeds and such sings), you will improve the structure of your markup by using a close to english language, using a single sentence and then use css styles to put the content in two lines.

That's what CSS is for, set the apparence of your content. In your case you use HTML which is intended to structure your content. Changing HTML purpose is the cause of your issue.

```
<h2>
<span>who</span> we are
</h2>
```

with a style that will lead to a one liner span should do the job :

```
h2 span {
  display: block;
}
```

Or anyone of the others solutions to this simple CSS behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&nbsp;`

```html
<h2>
<span>who</span>&nbsp;
<br/>we are
</h2>
```