# AJAX: StringBuilder does not retain new line when returned from WebMethod in AJAX call

Tags: c#, ajax, stringbuilder, webmethod

I have an `AJAX` call to `Web Method`. `Web Method` returns some statistics.  When I build a `StringBuilder`, I use `AppendFormat` and `AppendLine` methods to build it. However, when data is displayed, it is missing new lines.

This is an `AJAX` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GeneratePdfs",
    data: JSON.stringify({
           frequency:      $('#ddlReportFrequency option:selected').text(), 
           reportYear:     $('#txtReportYear').val(), 
           reportMonth:    $('#txtReportMonth').val(), 
           reportDay:      $('#txtReportDay').val(),
           reportOption:   $('#ddlReportOption option:selected').text(),
           reportRegion:   $('#txtReportRegion').val(),
           reportSchedule: $('#ddlReportSchedule').val(), 
           reportRegion:   $('#txtReportRegion').val()
   }), 
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function (data) {
       debugger;
       if (data.d != "") {
            $('#rptDisplay').text(data.d);
       }
   }
});
```

In my `Web Method`, I'm doing something like this:

```
sb.AppendFormat("\nData {0} does not have any statements", data);
sb.AppendLine();

return sb.ToString()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `#rptDisplay`? You'll probably need a html line break instead.

Comment: it is an id of a `div` tag that displays the data and `<br  />` does not work as well

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space