# "Unfolding" tags inserts space between lines

Tags: html, css

I imagine this is a duplicate question, but as someone who is relatively inexperienced in HTML I don't know exactly what to search, and I couldn't find a direct answer from the google searches I tried.

I'm writing HTML for the sidebar for an older website. The sidebar is nothing fancy - a small image at the top, followed by a number of plaintext links listed below it, placed at the side of the webpage with a css styling. Each link takes this form:

```
<a href="/subpage/"><span class="c2">Subpage</span></a><br>
```

In an effort to make the document somewhat more readable, I've expanded the various links to the following:

```
<a href="/subpage/">
    <span class="c2">Subpage</span>
</a>
<br>
```

However, when I do this, a few extra pixels of padding are placed above and below each link. Ultimately, the combined added padding causes the links to end up overlapping an element lower on the page, which I don't want.

I'm already aware that [HTML converts a newline to a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space), but this appears to be a distinctly different problem. I'm curious to know what causes this padding to appear, given that I have difficulty replicating it in the online HTML playground.

Below is a mockup of the sidebar's HTML and the parts of the CSS files I believe are relevant:

```css
body{
    margin: 1px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding:1px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-image: url(../../images/ribbon.jpg);
}

#lh-col{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 110px;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
}

#rh-col{
    margin: 0px 21px 0px 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

span.c2 {color: #004080; font-family: Arial; font-size: 85%}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="lh-col">
        <p>
            <a href="/">
                <img src="images/logo.gif" border="0" alt="Text" width="33" height="22">
            </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="/page1/">
                <span class="c2">Page 1</span>
            </a>
            <br>
            <a href="/page2/">
                <span class="c2">Page 2</span>
            </a>
            <br>
            <a href="/page3/">
                <span class="c2">Page 3</span>
            </a>
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="rh-col">
        <!-- The rest of the page... -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: One solution is to not "unfold" the tags

Comment: @StefanBob well obviously that's the easiest solution, but if nothing else I'd like to understand why this edit is causing unintuitive behavior so I can step away with a better knowledge of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to add display block to your `a` tags

Also if I was coding this I wouldn't even include the `p` tag or the `br` tag. Unless you need them for some reason.

```css
body {
  margin: 1px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 1px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: url(../../images/ribbon.jpg);
}

#lh-col {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 110px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

#rh-col {
  margin: 0px 21px 0px 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}

span.c2 {
  color: #004080;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 85%
}

#lh-col p a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="lh-col">
    <p>
      <a href="/">
        <img src="images/logo.gif" border="0" alt="Text" width="33" height="22">
      </a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="/page1/">
        <span class="c2">Page 1</span>
      </a>
      <a href="/page2/">
        <span class="c2">Page 2</span>
      </a>
      <a href="/page3/">
        <span class="c2">Page 3</span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="rh-col">
    <!-- The rest of the page... -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Or you can be more semantic and make it simple with flexbox:

```css
nav {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: That appears to cause even larger spaces between the links. As far as the `p` and `br` tags go, I'm whittling away at this site bit by bit because I'm not 100% sure what's necessary in the context of the site and what's not. It's not exactly the cleanest document. Also because removing the `br` tags puts all the links on one wrapping line.

Comment: I edit answer and removed br. Looks good? I added a second cleaner method if you can rework the code a little more. No spacing issues with flexbox ;)

Comment: I'd wait for another answer if you are looking for the how and why of that white space

Comment: The `block` solution did solve my core problem, so I'm inclined to give this the answer, but I am still curious as to the why. I'll probably wait a few minutes and mark this as an answer later.

Comment: I'll also probably look into `nav` and `flexbox` later; for now I just need to tidy up with minimal changes, and then I can probably use the `nav` solution later once I have more breathing room. Double kudos.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers are notorious for adding extra padding between inline elements, https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/, when there is a line break or space between them in the HTML. There's several ways to circumvent this:

1. Use an HTML minifier, http://minifycode.com/html-minifier/. (or a workflow tool would be more efficient)
2. Rewrite your HTML to remove the spaces manually. The only necessary part to focus on is having no space between one element's closing tag and the next element's open tag. i.e. `</a><a>`
3. The flexbox solution mentioned in other answers.
4. Adjust your CSS to compensate for a scenario where two `<a>` are next to each other and negative margin the second one (do not recommend this but it is an option).
   `a + a{margin-left: -4px;}`

Comment: So in other words, it's basically just the way it is. Well, good to know for the future.

Answer (score 1):

An old hack is to hide the spaces using comments:

```
<a href="/subpage/"><!--
    --><span class="c2">Subpage</span><!--
--></a>
```

Of course, this causes the code to be more ugly to work with.