# New lines (\n) in html table cell

Tags: html, css

Got content with new lines in a cell:

[image]

This is not show in table:
[image]

As you can see, I have added "overflow-wrap: break-word". Not working.

What CSS should I add to make this work?

Comment: White space is collapsed in HTML. Use `white-space: pre`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the browser renders a newline as space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space)

Comment: white-space: pre puts everything on one row.

Comment: If you'd like to provide your code as text rather than a picture of text, I could create a fiddle showing it working. May have something to do with the use of a `span` element that's inline rather than block.

Comment: use a div tag instead!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to insert a `<br>` after "some text" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no much information in your question, but maybe you just need to replace all the new line characters (\n) by a **br** tag.