# Why cannot my button tag be centred as other input tags?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use HTML and CSS create a search box with a text input tag and a button input tag both centered within it. But the CSS code does not work to my button tag though it works to the other tag.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}

.search-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3, -2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3;
}

#input-search {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  margin: 9px 10px 9px 9px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 3px;
}

#btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #008080;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 9px 9px 9px 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#20B2AA, #5F9EA0);
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" id="input-search" placeholder="search">
  <input type="button" value="GO" id="btn">
</div>
```

Based on my calculation, the margin on both sides is supposed to make the two tags perfectly centred in the div, but there seems to be some padding or margin which `*{margin:0; padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}` cannot clear.

The button cannot be either centered vertically or be displayed in line with the text tag.Can anyone please help me fix the button tag?

Here is the full code: https://codepen.io/mayiscoding/pen/qBxLbYb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on my calculation, the margin on both sides is supposed to make the two tags perfectly centred in the div

Your calculation is not fully correct, what you do is `200+9+10+50+9` which is `278`, which seems to fit into the element with the width `278`. But what you didn't include is the space between the two `input` elements introduced by the new line ([Why does the browser renders a newline as space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space)).

If you remove that new line it will work:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}

.search-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3, -2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3;
}

#input-search {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  margin: 9px 10px 9px 9px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 3px;
}

#btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #008080;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 9px 9px 9px 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#20B2AA, #5F9EA0);
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" id="input-search" placeholder="search"><!--
  --><input type="button" value="GO" id="btn">
</div>
```

But to avoid such problems, you might want to use `display: flex` instead of manually calculating the correct widths of the elements.

- set the `display` of your `.search-box` to `flex`.
- remove the `width` and `height` of both `input` elements, flex will handle that.
- instead of setting a `width` to `#btn` set the desired `padding`.
- use `flex: 1 1 auto;` on your `#input-search` to make it stretch and use the available size.

That way you can change the `width` of your `.search-box` without the need to change the width of the input elements, and you can update the font size of the button and the text. You can even make the `.search-box` responsive, by changing `with` to `max-width`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}

.search-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3, -2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3;
  display: flex;
}

#input-search {
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  margin: 9px 10px 9px 9px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 3px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#btn {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #008080;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 9px 9px 9px 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#20B2AA, #5F9EA0);
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" id="input-search" placeholder="search">
  <input type="button" value="GO" id="btn">
</div>
```

To further improve the CSS I would remove the `margin` from the `input` elements, and change it to a `padding` on the `.search-box` and `gap`. And instead of a `px` unit for `padding` for the `#btn` I would use `em`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}

.search-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3, -2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3;
  display: flex;
  padding: 9px;
  gap: 10px;
}

#input-search {
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 3px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#btn {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #008080;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1.2em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#20B2AA, #5F9EA0);
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" id="input-search" placeholder="search">
  <input type="button" value="GO" id="btn">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation and solution! Very helpful for beginners :)

Answer (score 1):

By removing this `margin: 9px 9px 9px 0;` you have on `#btn`, you have I think what you want.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}

.search-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3, -2px 2px 1px #D3D3D3;
}

#input-search {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  margin: 9px 10px 9px 9px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 3px;
}

#btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #008080;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#20B2AA, #5F9EA0);
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" id="input-search" placeholder="search">
  <input type="button" value="GO" id="btn">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is not the `margin: 9px 9px 9px 0;` but the space between the two `input` elements, which makes the total width of both `input` elements larger than the width of the `search-box` (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put a display from inline-block to block and change the margin to 9px auto. The auto will center the button horizontally.

Comment: Far better to use a snippet where possible

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
#btn{
    margin: 9px auto;
}
```

Comment: Far better to use a snippet where possible